# No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive in ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

Working in Ionic 2, then upgrading to 3 to try to fix this error.  It began when I was trying to figure out a cordova plugin.  The archive doesnt appear to be signed correctly.

```
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **


2017-10-03 14:40:10.745 xcodebuild[4293:73077] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/12/9djblkvn1_7g0_41crqy9ht00000gn/T/Omnidispatch_2017-10-03_14-40-10.744.xcdistributionlogs'.

2017-10-03 14:40:10.965 xcodebuild[4293:73077] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7fa1dde9d300>: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive}

error: exportArchive: No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive

Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No 'teamID' specified and no team ID found in the archive}


** EXPORT FAILED **


Error: Error code 70 for command: xcodebuild with args: -exportArchive,-archivePath,Omnidispatch.xcarchive,-exportOptionsPlist,/Developer/omnisolutions/omni-ionic/platforms/ios/exportOptions.plist,-exportPath,/Developer/omnisolutions/omni-ionic/platforms/ios/build/device
```

There have been a few solutions that suggest that its not the team id, but rather a certificate error.  I'm not very good with mac certificates, but they seem to be in place and I've not changed them since this broke.

I have gone into xcode a time or two and the team was not saved, I've fixed that every time I've seen it and it seems to be staying there now, but its still not changing anything when i run `ionic build ios`

What else can I check?

I should add, that it builds in xcode 8, but not in vscode or on the commandline as it did previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I did not find a great solution for this error.  I was forced to rm -rf my directory, uninstall ionic and cordova and bring it all down from git and set it up again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue during a ionic cordova build without signature (for 
pro MDM):

> ionic build ios --release --device
>   --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"

finally I smash it using a build.json at the root folder with only the developmentTeam Info filled

```
{
"ios": {
    "debug": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "Apple Development: BLa BLa (XXXXXXX)",
        "provisioningProfile": "<XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX>",
        "provisioningProfileFile": "embedded.mobileprovision",
        "certificateFile": "blabla.p12",
        "developmentTeam": "<TEAMID>"
    },
    "release": {
        "codeSignIdentity": "",
        "provisioningProfile": "",
        "provisioningProfileFile": "",
        "certificateFile": "",
        "developmentTeam": "<TEAMID>"
    }
}
```

}

Hope it's help you